# What's a good data structure for a 24hr minute-by-minute boolean record

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am tasked to create a data structure that holds a boolean for every minute of the last 24hrs. *(Did event X occur?)* I need to keep the last 24hrs all the time. (That is, data will constantly be added, old data popped off.) The data is to be persisted to a flash drive. We are on an embedded platform, but memory isn't that limited (I have 128MB available), fragmentation might become a problem, though. This is a realtime system, but since the record is per minute, there's little runtime constraints.

The interface could look something like this:

```
class x_record {
  public:
    // record whether or not x occurred this minute
    void record_entry(bool x_occured);

    // how many minutes has x occured in the last 24hrs? 
    unsigned int x_occurance_minutes() const;

  private:
    // HERE BE DRAGONS 
};
```

What would be a good data structure to store the actual data in? My current favorites are `std::deque<bool>` and an array of 24 `long long`, with 60 of their 64 bits each used for the 60mins of an hour. The latter is the current favorite for persistence.

I think I have a pretty good idea about the pros and cons of both ideas, but would hope some of you could provide additional insides and maybe even more ideas.

P.S.: This is strictly C++03 + TR1 + Boost 1.52, no C++11/14 available.

Comment: Sounds like you need a ring buffer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by *good*? Fast? Compact? Beautiful? Maintainable? Something else?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<bool>`? It's rather economical.

Comment: How important is memory efficiency vs. processor efficiency? Is the interface you posted complete (if not, what other operations will be performed on this data structure)? Is the record a "sliding window" where it gets updated every minute? Is it necessary to preserve each bit with the corresponding time, or is only the aggregate event count important? How often are calculations performed?

Comment: @Frédéric It should be maintainable, fast, compact, beautiful, and well-behaved. If it brews good coffee, then that's a nice extra. `:)`

Comment: @dvnrrs I have written about the constraints. What's missing from the interface is persistence (writing to/loading from disk). If there are other operations required, I do not know of them yet.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I dunno, as most of us I have heeded the advice and shunned `vector<bool>`. What about `push_front()`/`pop_back()` on it?

Comment: @sbi My understanding is that you wouldn't need either one of them: you allocate a `vector<bool>(24*60, false)`, and run with it. Internally, it would have the same footprint as an array of longs, plus two pointers. The chance of it fragmenting your heap would be pretty slim, too, because all allocations would happen in the same exact size of 180 bytes.

Comment: Oh, wasn't this clear? This is about a rolling 24hrs record. IOW, I need to minutely push new data to it and pop off old data.

Comment: Do you have any estimate on the distribution of true vs. false? In some cases a more compact representation might be more convenient, eg. sequence of pairs of last value, count.

Comment: Sure Nicolla Musatti, why not do a on-the-fly run-length encoding? It might squeeze the 192 bytes per day he needs right now to store his data by a significant amount!

Comment: @NicolaMusatti It is very likely that the event will always occur for several minutes at a time. However, it _could_ be that it occurs every other minute.

Comment: An alternative is to use `std::bitset`.

Comment: @Alec: Please do not change my code in such a controversial fashion. I do not believe protected data is a good design. In fact, I consider `protected` an evil that is sometimes necessary (like `friend`), but should be used as little as possible.

Comment: A fixed array can keep a rolling record, too - all you need is an `int` that shows where the data starts. The class behaves like a circular queue with only one "pointer" (the second pointer is always one away, because all 24 hours are used).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, but then what is the advantage over the array of `long long`?

Comment: I like the *"array of 24 `long long`, with 60 of their 64 bits each used for the 60mins of an hour"* idea.  It will make things easier if you ever want to analyze a single hour by itself.

Comment: @japreiss as per the standard, array allocations are continuous. (legacy sort of, pointer arithmetic after all!) so an array of any type made of bits works.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight love the name and EXACTLY! Why are we the first to realise this! (my answer got downvoted!) Static allocation, there is NO heap fragmentation then, which was mentioned!

Comment: @AlecTeal throwing away 4 bits of a 64-bit integer means that the bits for a single hour line up on machine word boundaries nicely, so it's easier to extract them without math and shifting operations.

Comment: @japreiss 24 is divisible by 8. It's also not easier to extract them that way. If you have some weird prime-number of bits overflow that'd never align consistently and be a bitch, dealing with 8s for a computer is not hard, and 64 may be divided by 8, so more data aligns with the words :)

Comment: @Marius: I looked into this and `std::bitset` seems to be designed just for this. It perfectly fits the requirements, so that's what I ended up using. If you write an answer suggesting `std::bitset`, I'd upvote and accept that. (Otherwise I'll have to write it in order to be able to accept one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested by Marius Bancila first [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612680/whats-a-good-data-structure-for-a-24hr-minute-by-minute-boolean-record/22680124#comment34432473_22612680) and then [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612680/whats-a-good-data-structure-for-a-24hr-minute-by-minute-boolean-record/22680124#22680124) (please go and upvote that answer, he gave the hint that turned out to be the solution), `std::bitset<>` is ideal for this. However, since his answer is rather vague, I decided to post a more concrete description of what I ended up using:

```
class x_record {
  public:
    void record_entry(bool x_occured) {
      record_ <<= 1;
      record_[0] = x_occurred;
    }

    unsigned int x_occurance_minutes() const {
      return record_.count();
    }

    void write_to(std::ostream& os) const {
      os << m_overload_minutes.to_string();
    }

    void read_from(std::istream& is) const {
      std::string bits;
      is >> std::setw(minutes_to_keep) >> bits;
      if( !is || bits.size()!=minutes_to_keep )
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid file format");

      record_ = std::bitset<60*24>(bits);
    }

  private:
    std::bitset<60*24>  record_;
};
```

As you can see, `std::bitset<>` is pretty much exactly what I needed. Also, persisting the data is very easy.

Of course, in reality, this was a bit more complex<sup>1</sup>, but in principle this is indeed the whole thing.

Thanks to everyone for trying to help me!

<sup>1</sup> It turned out that it was easier to call `x_occurance_minutes()` every few msecs, for which `record_.count()` seemed quite some overhead, so I called it in `record_entry()` (called once per minute only) instead and cached the result.

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on the `vector<bool>` version, I think it's quite a good idea, since you **always** store the same amount of data (that's at least what I understood):

```
class x_record {
   vector<bool> data;
   unsigned int currentMinute;

public:
   x_record(): data(24*60, false), currentMinute(0){}

   // record whether or not x occurred this minute
   void record_entry(bool x_occured){
      data[currentMinute] = x_occured;
      currentMinute = (currentMinute+1)%data.size();
   }

};
```

This way, the vector size is constant so it *shouldn't* be fragmented (since it's allocated all at the same time). You can keep track of the current minute with the `currentMinute` variable. When you fill all the fields, you just set it to `0` with `%(24*60)` and **overwrite** the old data, since you don't need it.

You could also use a normal **array** instead of a `vector<bool>`, but that would require either more space (since normally C++ stores `bool` values the same way as a `char`), or some bit manipulation which is - in my opinion - reinventing the wheel, when we got the `vector<bool>` specialization.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad idea. `+1` from me.

Comment: +1 I would have given the same answer. Instead of hardcoding `24*60` in `record_entry` though, I would have just used `data.size()`. Also, the `unsigned int x_occurance_minutes() const;` method requested by the OP would be just `return std::count( data.begin(), data.end(), true );`

Comment: This is just an ordinary ring buffer and it is a bit tricky to look an event up, because you have to figure out where it is in the ring buffer, first the vector element, then the bit in question.

Comment: You could construct the `data` member with the correct size straight away, using `data(24*60, false)` in the initializer list.

Answer (score 6):

A circular buffer:

```
int countBits(std::uint32_t v) {
  // source: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel
  typedef std::uint32_t T;
  v = v - ((v >> 1) & (T)~(T)0/3);                           // temp
  v = (v & (T)~(T)0/15*3) + ((v >> 2) & (T)~(T)0/15*3);      // temp
  v = (v + (v >> 4)) & (T)~(T)0/255*15;                      // temp
  return (T)(v * ((T)~(T)0/255)) >> (sizeof(T) - 1) * CHAR_BIT; // count
}

class x_record {
  public:
    x_record() { std::memset(&history, 0, sizeof(history)); }

    // record whether or not x occurred this minute
    void record_entry(bool x_occured) {
      uint64_t mask = 1 << (bit % 32);
      uint64_t set = x_occured ? mask : 0;
      history[bit / 32] = (history[bit / 32] & ~mask) | set;

      bit = (bit + 1) % (24*60);
    }

    // how many minutes has x occured in the last 24hrs? 
    int x_occurance_minutes() const {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<45; ++i) {
        count += countBits(history[i]);
      }
      return count;
    }

  private:
    std::uint32_t history[45];
    short bit = 0;
};
```

Comment: That's the bit hackery I thought I'd use `long long` for. Is there any advantage in using a 32bit integer over a 64bit one? (Oh, and `+1`, since this, too, answers the question.)

Comment: @sbi 24 * 60 is evenly divisible by 32, so there's no extra space used. You could use `uint64_t` as well, but I found that this bit counting routine only works for types up to 32 bits. You'd have to update both `countBits()` and the constants used in `x_record`.

Answer (score 3):

I would have a `std::vector<bool>` for every hour and only ditch hourly. So you could have a `std::deque<std::vector<bool> >`. Likewise it could be a `std::deque<long long>` but I don't see a benefit as compared to the vector.

It makes things efficient, easy to understand and less error prone.

Comment: That is two vastly different ideas, presented only as skeletons, and pros and cons not addressed at all. Sorry, but that's a `-1` from me.

Comment: Why cant we statically allocate (see my answer)

Comment: @sbi Where do I present two vastly different ideas? I only see one idea in my answer, and that is to have one dequeue item per hour. It is basically a compromise between your two suggestions.

Comment: @ypnos: A `vector<bool>` allows accessing the booleans as (if they were) actual `bool` objects, while `std::deque<long long>` (note the spelling of the container, BTW) requires me to fiddle with the bits myself. Basically, that boils down to the two opposite suggestions I made in my question.

Comment: Maybe you should word your question more carefully and I also think you didn't get the quintessence of my answer, the long long is only a sidenote.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, `std::bitset` might be a good choice. It's a fixed-size sequence of bits that can be manipulated independently. It takes less memory than a `std::vector<bool>` (even thought you said this is not a problem for you). You might however need to wrap it in another container if you need to make the sequence circular, so that you always keep the last 24*60 minutes, not the 24*60 minutes of a day.

Comment: I suggested boost.dynamic_bitset because I mistakenly thought that std::bitset had a maximum size (as suggested by the constructor and the to_ulong() function), but this is not the case and the number of bits is known at startup, so std::bitset is a better fit.

Comment: In the end, I posted (and accepted) [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22939475/140719), since yours what a bit vague, but you certainly turned me into the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you are only concerned on how often the event occurred in the last 24 hours, and can completely neglect the time when it occurred, you can simply record the occurences.

Consider the following (not tested):

```
class x_record {
public:
  // record whether or not x occurred this minute
  void record_entry(bool x_occured) {
    if (x_occured) {
      m_records.insert(getTime());
    }
  }

  // how many minutes has x occured in the last 24hrs? 
  unsigned int x_occurance_minutes() {
    clearRecords();
    return m_records.size();
  }

private:
    time_t getTime() const {
      return time(NULL) / 60; // Get Minute time stamp
    }

    void clearRecords() {
      // Erase all records that happend before the last 24 hours
      time_t frameStart = getTime() - 60*60*24;
      for (std::set<time_t>::iterator it = m_recods.begin(); it != m_records.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it < frameStart) {
          m_records.erase(it);
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

private:
    std::set<time_t> m_records;
};
```

This is suitable best if events occur sparsely.

It uses the constrain that sets store their elements in a strict weak ordering, so that elements with lower time stamp will be listed first. Also

You should consider a different key type for inserting into the set, as `time_t` is not guaranteed to represent seconds.

Comment: This is an interesting idea (`+1`). But the event can occur for up to several dozen minutes in 24hrs, it's not unlikely that it occurs several dozen times, and the timestamp on this platform is 64bit. Given these circumstances (which I believe I hadn't stated that clearly in my question), I guess using your idea would be inferior.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a class containing [boost.dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), a counter for handling the storing of the new value and a conversion function for accessing via hour/minute.

The dynamic_set handles most of the requirements:

- boost, no C++11
- compact
- handles 24*60 bits
- has a count() function for counting set bits
- returns blocks for storing as bits
- doesn't have the "container" issues of std::vector

Comment: Sounds interesting (`+1`). How would I push to/pop from such a beast?

Comment: Just increment and modulo the counter and use it to index the next bit.  After the first iteration, the oldest value will be overwritten.  BTW, boost also has circular buffer, but not optimized for bits...

Comment: Actually, that part is the same as for the vector<bool> solution.