# Container of fixed size where older elements will be deleted

Tags: c++, std, poco

Is there container adaptor in **std** or **Poco** that allows to specify size of it and where I can push element and in case if it will be full new element will be added in place of older one (or will be added at the end but first element will be deleted and all rest elements will be moved on one position back).

For instance imagine that container with size = 3.

I am pushing 4 elements [1, 2, 3, 4] consequentially into it and as a result I am getting that container with [2, 3, 4] or [4, 2, 3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the structure you're looking for is called a **circular buffer**. C++ doesn't offer a container that represents that kind of structure, but it can be written pretty easily when you use a `vector` as the underlaying container.

In order to get an idea of how to actually implement it, you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612680/whats-a-good-data-structure-for-a-24hr-minute-by-minute-boolean-record), where the OP asked about a similar structure, but operating on bools. The only difference between your problem and his is that you actually need a **templated** class, so it would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class circularBuffer {
   vector<T> data;
   unsigned int lastEntryPos;

   // methods to access "data"
};
```

You could also add a second template parameter indicating the size of the underlaying vector, and set it in the constructor:

```
template <typename T, size_type size>
class circularBuffer {
   // ...
   circularBuffer(): data(size), lastEntryPos(0){};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a container `list` or `vector`, then before insert element, check container's size, if meet the count, popup old element, then push new one.
each time, you can iterate list in reverse sequence to get the element as their insert sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> q;
    for(int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
    {
        if(q.size() < 3)
            q.push_front(m);
        else
        {
            q.pop_back();
            q.push_front(m);
        }
    }

    for(auto x = q.rbegin(); x != q.rend(); x++)
        std::cout << *x;

    return 0;
}
```

output `789`